# How to use pre-populated sqlite database in UWP?

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, uwp, xamarin.uwp

This is my 1st attempt to make cross-platform app using Visual Studio 2015. With the help from tutorials available on net, I was able to use SQLite in UWP (Xamarin Forms). But, I don't know how to copy pre-populated sqlite database and use that?

My code sample is -

```
using Medical_Study.UWP;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Storage;
using Xamarin.Forms;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(SqliteService))]

namespace Medical_Study.UWP
{

    public class SqliteService : ISQLite
    {
        public SqliteService()
        {
        }
        #region ISQLite implementation
        public SQLite.SQLiteConnection GetConnection()
        {
            var sqliteFilename = "QBank.db";
            string path = Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, sqliteFilename);
            var conn = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(path);

            // Return the database connection 
            return conn;
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To deploy pre-populated SQLite DB "QBank.db" you could compile it as an embedded resource of the application and on first run copy it into the `LocalFolder` for further use.

To do this include the "QBank.db" into your project and select `Build Action -> Embedded Resource`.

`GetConnection()` method can be implemented like this:

```
public SQLite.SQLiteConnection GetConnection()
{
  var sqliteFilename = "QBank.db";

  var assembly = GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
  var qbankDbResource 
    = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames().FirstOrDefault(name => name.EndsWith(sqliteFilename));
  if (qbankDbResource == null)
  {
    Debug.Assert(false, string.Format("{0} database is not included as embedded resource", sqliteFilename));
    return null;
  }

  string path = Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, sqliteFilename);
  using (var qbankDbStream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(qbankDbResource))
  using (var fStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
  {
    qbankDbStream.CopyTo(fStream);
  }

  var conn = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(path);
  // Return the database connection 
  return conn;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I was asking specifically about UWP (Universal Windows Programming), in that it's showing error - `'Application' does not contain a definition for 'GetResourceStream'.` For iOS & android I had already made it work from another tutorial on net. And I am not using WP8

Comment: @Dr.AtulTiwari Added UWP info to the answer. Please check

Comment: Thank you, but I am still having doubts. What is `someObj` here?

Comment: @Dr.AtulTiwari It's literally any object, type of which declared in the same assembly as your resources. E.g. in your `GetConnection()` function you could use `this.GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly`.

Comment: thank you for your constant help. I got your point now. It seems I am yet to learn many things before I could make a basic app. I tried to search **how to copy stream to target file in uwp**, but so far whatever I found is not helpful in my case. Anyways I will read more about it in my free time, right now hospital duty time :(

Comment: @Dr.AtulTiwari I've simplified my answer and leave only relevant information. Now `QBank.db` included as an embedded resource and copied to LocalFolder during `GetConnection()` execution

Comment: Thank you for the updated answer. It certainly helped me. Although before reading your answer, I also tried using `StorageFile` but it didn't work out for me, something I might be missing. But, your method worked. Thanks

Comment: @Dr.AtulTiwari How did you made worked in iOS and Android? please can you suggest me some links or ideas.